# can I add a vertical swiping gesture to AdapterViewFlipper in widget?

Tags: android, widget

I'm working on an [**Android widget**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) which contains a AdapterViewFlipper. The AdapterViewFlipper can automatically flips the views (each view including ). But can we manually switch to next or prev view by **vertically swiping**? Is this automatically supported by AdapterViewFlipper (similar to StackView) or I have to add gesture listener in each view?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd like to clarify my question. The AdapterViewFlipper is in a widget, in which what we can get is always RemoteViews. In such a case, can I still add GestureListener to the view?

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html#detect
You can do this using a GestureDetector

```
private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;
```

```
mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureListener());
```

You can then either @Override the onTouchEvent of the Activity.

```
@Override 
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 
        this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Or you can also setOnTouchListener for your AdapterViewFlipper

```
 avf.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         return mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
     }
 });
```

```
class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures"; 

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) { 
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"onDown: " + event.toString()); 
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent start, MotionEvent finish, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        if (start.getRawY() < finish.getRawY()) {
            //down
        } else {
            //up
        }
    return true;
    }
}
```

This may help too
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/android-app-builder/use-androids-gesture-detector-to-translate-a-swipe-into-an-event/

Comment: Sorry, but there seems some misunderstanding about my question. The AdapterViewFlipper is in a widget, in which what we can get is always RemoteViews. In such a case, can I still add GestureListener to the view?

Comment: Yes you can add a touch listener to any view and in the ontouch of that pass the event on to your gesture listener